# Prevent SQL Server Management Studio from removing alias in views (designtime)?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

In my customer table, I have a column called `name` (lower cases).

If I in a view put `Name` (camel case) in the alias for the column above, save changes, close the view and open it again ... now the alias is removed and I'm back to the lowercase.

In TSQL I can use `SELECT name AS Name` and it works fine.

How can I prevent my camelcase alias being removed when only the casing is different from the column to the alias?

Comment: Simple: ***don't*** use the designer. It's a terribly buggy, feature lacking, quirky, and as good as deprecated mess. Learn to write the T-SQL and then never look back.

Comment: (blind shot) What if you change the statement to `SELECT Name`? Will it stick?